# Android start Method after ending phone call

Tags: android

I am developing an app and have been able to start a phone call inside the app but when it end I want to resume the app with the information preserved and a pop up to come up.

I have been able to dial the call and get the pop up to come up in seperate instances but unable to put them together.  This question has been answered in March of this year but I wanted to see if anyone else has come up with a better idea.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the Activity Life cycle diagram, when a phone call is received application calls `onPause()` method. What I can think of is for you to do a saving of your data using `SharedPreferences` writing data from a thread which will run regardless if the application is not visible anymore to the user, either you do this in the call listener or in `onPause()` method. But more practical approach is to use `onSaveInstanceState()` method where you put all the relevant data which will be restored lately in `onRestoreInstanceState()` method.

[image: Another activity comes in front]

Read more here how they work:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

In the `PhoneStateListener` class you can use some `flags` to mark if the call has taken place, when going to `CALL_STATE_RINGING` state, and then in the `CALL_STATE_IDLE` check whether call is made because IDLE state is occuring all the time when the phone is doing nothing, but when you have a flag you can check `if(flag)` do something and change the flag, so whenever the listener is again in `CALL_STATE_IDLE` your flag will be inverted so no actions again will be taken. Just an idea.

***Edit:*** Add the the PhoneStateListener class as inner class in your activity/service class and register phone state listener using `TelephonyManager`. I hope you'll find your way

```
public class MyClassActivity extends Activity
{
    ....
    //set here your call listener here 

}



protected class PhoneState extends PhoneStateListener{
        private boolean mCall=false;
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {


             switch(state)
             {
             case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                 mCall=true;  //fire the flag that there is call ongoing 
                 break;
             case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if(mCall)
                {
                  mCall=false; //Reverting the flag, indicating you are aware that there was call
                  // Here do the rest of your operation you want
                }
                 break;

            default:
                }      
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is so helpful! I am floored by this concept.  You wouldn't know where I could find an example of this in action?  I am trying to wrap my head around this whole concept.  Thank you Nikola!

Comment: I added the idea about phone state listener. If you want me, I'll try something to write for you for the SharedPrefs, onSaveInstnc(),onRstrInstnc()...But I think there are quite much examples on these few. Cheers.

Comment: This is unbelievable perfect!